# How to format datetime to only specific DATE format in datatable

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datagridview, datatable

In my datagridview1, the DATE column show format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

Then I use this code.

I use a function to fill a datagridview like this

```
public void load_table()
{
    DataTable ltdgv = getLoad_table(); 
    //the getLoad_table() function return a datatable type and store it to ltdgv

   foreach (DataRow dr in ltdgv.Rows)
   {
       dr["DATE"] = DateTime.Parse((dr["DATE"].ToString())).ToShortDateString();
   }

   dataGridView1.DataSource = ltdgv;           
}
```

but the DATE column still showing format MM/dd/yyyy [ex: 11/27/2016]

but I want to change it to dd/MM/yyyy or 27/11/2016

I tried to change it into =

```
dr["DATE"] = DateTime.Parse((dr["DATE"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))).ToShortDateString();
// I fill a parameter to the .ToString()
```

But I now get a "syntax error".

So, how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not try to change the 'format' of a datetime column in a datatable.
Simply a DateTime has no format by itself.

It is the tool that you use to display the date that has the task to present it in a *human readable* format, whatever this format is.

In other words. It is the DataGridView that must carry out this task.

You just need to set

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

(Assuming that the grid column at index zero is your date column)

Comment: Your answer is awesome, Thank you.
I googled this kind of question, and I dont think I found the same answer as yours.

Answer (score 4):

Place the custom format in the output `ToString()`, not the input.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ltdgv.Rows)
{
    dr["DATE"] = DateTime.Parse((dr["DATE"].ToString())).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In case of asp:BoundField**

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="BirthDate" HeaderText="Birth Date" DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"  />
```

**In case of asp:TemplateField**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Birth Date" ItemStyle-Width="120px" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("BirthDate", "{0:dd, MMM yyyy}") %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```