# How can I store a formatted DateTime into column of type DateTime in Database?

Tags: c#, datetime, pdf-generation, console-application, datetime-format

I'm retrieving data from the database in a dataset and printing it in a pdfdocument. One table has got a DateTime column and the value comes as `"12/27/2018 12:00:00 AM"`. I'm trying to format that as `dd/MM/yyyy` but with no success since it is expecting a DateTime and formatting return a string value. Should I change the column datatype or there is a way to maintain it and format the datetime?

Comment: " but with no success" what does it mean, what kind of errors do you get, please a code snippet

Comment: You can't directly format a DateTime, you can however format how it get's displayed. I'm not a WinForms or even DataTable expert, but I'm pretty sure you can give a DateTime column a format. Also possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40947319/9363973

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format datetime to only specific DATE format in datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947319/how-to-format-datetime-to-only-specific-date-format-in-datatable)

Comment: Formatting is no responsibility of the data layer, but should be done in the UI only.

Comment: You cannot set format to DateTime field in dataset. Formatting is applied when you show this data on user interface. What kind of ui control are you using (DataGridView, Label,...)?

Comment: @MindSwipe Formatting how it gets displayed probably means as a string value? Because then I would have to change the datatype of the table column before filling it.

Comment: @Kodre Im not using any ui control, I get the data from the database and just print it in a pdfdocument using pdfsharper.

Comment: If you're printing this in a pdf document please state so in the question and tags. I was assuming (and yes I know what assuming makes out of you and me) you were talking about the "DataTable" UI element from WinForms

Comment: @Popplar Can you post here segment of code where you are writing data to pdfDocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend changing the database from string to DateTime.  But if you cannot you can use something like this

```
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone();

            //change columns type
            dt2.Columns["Col A"].DataType = typeof(DateTime);
            int colNumber = dt2.Columns.IndexOf("Col A");

            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.AsEnumerable())
            {
                object[] rowData = row.ItemArray;
                rowData[colNumber] = DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("Col A"));
                dt2.Rows.Add(rowData);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do, cloning and changing the datatype of that column and finally populating it again.